# css positioning (z-index) element behind element

Tags: html, css, positioning, z-index

I'm trying to make the following html/css layout:

[http://siteique.com/uploads/1.png http://siteique.com/uploads/1.png](http://siteique.com/uploads/1.png) .

My problem is with the blue lines behind the main `div`.

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- blue line 1 -->
    <div style="width:100%; height:60px; background-color:#81b7ff; position:absolute; top:385px; z-index:1; float:left;"></div>

    <div id="site">
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <!-- blue line 2 -->
        <div style="position:relative; bottom:0px; height:200px; width:100%; z-index:1;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that if I make the `#site` `div` `position:absolute` and `z-index:2` the `#footer` won`t be in the position I want.

So what is the trick I need?

I'm trying to position the blue `div`'s behind the white `div` `#site`

Comment: just an fyi, your z-index is set to 1 in the footer

Comment: what are you trying to do? that image is so unclear...

Comment: I`m trying to position the blue div`s behind the white div ( #site )

Comment: http://siteique.com/uploads/1.png — Layout? Thats just some colored blocks of nonsense…

Comment: so... if you don`t know how the answer you begin with unneeded comments ?

Comment: the above image shows your problem or your desired layout you want??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that if I make `#site position:absolute` and
>   `z-index:2`…

If you just want to influence the stacking-context by adding a new layer, `position: relative;` would be appropriate and keeps the element flowing.

Please note also, that the »blue line 2« has a different stacking context then »blue line 1«, because the former is nested inside one more layer (#footer) then the latter.

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/stacking